# Cisco ASA 5505 inside interface multiple ip addresses

Tags: cisco-asa

I have an issue this morning where I want to be able to assign multiple ip addresses to the inside interface to facilitate an ip range migration for an office.

Namely from a 192.168.1.x range to the new range, with the minimum of interruption for those working in the office.

(New DHCP leases will use the new range, whilst those still on the 192.168.1.x range can continue to work until their lease is renewed).

However I can not for the life of me figure out how to achieve this, trying to create multiple interfaces for the job leads to complaints about the license only allowing 2 active interfaces.

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "small print" of [this page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/prod_models_comparison.html)

> Beginning with Cisco ASA Software v7.2.3, the ASA 5510 Security Plus license enables 2 10/100/1000 interfaces and 3 10/100 interfaces

It may be helpful

Comment: Accepted this answer after speaking with Cisco directly a license upgrade is required to achieve what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

On a regular Cisco router, you can just do "ip address ADDRESS MASK secondary"

On the ASA, you need a weird hackaround.

http://www.ducea.com/2008/05/31/adding-a-secondary-ip-address-on-a-cisco-asa-ethernet-interface

Comment: Didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the licensing scheme that you purchased with your ASA, you'll want to use [VLANS](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/getting_started/asa5505/quick/guide/vlans.html#wp1102615).